# Android background service for push notifications

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My app needs to be connected to a remote socket server in a background Service.

I need to "ALWAYS" run it in the background.
As already known - its imposible and not a good architectur to try and run a Service always because it will overload the system and system will kill it.

Can someone please advise on a way to still keep my service in a "listen" mode for push notification and still keep the socket connection alive using AlarmManager?